# Firestore batch does not complete forever if it exceeds a certain number of jobs

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
function writeBatch(buffer:Gallery[]):Promise<any>{
  const bat = firestore().batch()
  buffer.forEach(item=>{
    bat.set(item.id.getDocument(),item)
  })
  return bat.commit()
}
```

To speed up writing, I am updating the data in firestore using batch as in the code above.

However, if an average of 20,000 documents are created or updated in one runtime, subsequent batches never complete.

To solve this, I had to kill the client completely and then run it again.

This problem is occurring on both Android and NodeJS.

Is there anything I missed?

Comment: The documentation says: "Each transaction or batch of writes can write to a maximum of 500 documents". Sounds like you're exceeding the limit?  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions

Comment: The size of the array passed as a parameter never exceeds 500.

Comment: So you're saying that after repeated calls to writeBatch that things fail after the total number of documents written **so far** exceeds 20,000?

Comment: When the number of documents created so far exceeds 20,000, batch.commit() will not cause any errors and will not complete.

Comment: You should file a bug report in that case, if you have reproduction steps.  http://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features

Comment: My initial feeling is that you may be overloading the client. For example: calling `writeBatch` in a tight loop for that many documents will likely cause the client to run out of memory. If that is the case, try pacing the calls to `writeBatch`; for example call it once per second. If that fixes it, definitely file a bug report as Doug suggested, since the client *should* report such an error error explicitly.